# Gauss' lemma for arbitrary integral domains

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, ring-theory, polynomial-rings

One of the versions of the classical Gauss' lemma in abstract algebra states the following:

> **Theorem:** Let $R$ be an integral domain, $f\in R[X]$ of positive degree and $K$ the quotient field of $R$. If $R$ is a UFD, these facts are equivalent:
>
> i) $f$ is irreducible in $R[X]$.
>
> ii) $f$ is primitive in $R[X]$ and irreducible in $K[X]$.

This result, as Wikipedia points out, it's still valid when $R$ is a GCD domain. So my question is basically this: what is the weakest hypothesis we can assume in $R$ and still be able to guarantee that the above result is true?

Certainly we would have to change the usual definition of "primitive polynomial". I think it's appropriate to take a definition that is used in many research papers, namely we say that $f=a_0+a_1X+\ldots +a_nX^n$ is *primitive* if $(a_0,a_1,\ldots a_n)\subseteq (d)$ implies $d\in R^{\times}$, i.e., the only elements that divide all the coefficients of $f$ are the units of $R$.

It's easy to see that this definition agrees with the standard one: if $R$ is a GCD domain then $f$ is *primitive* iff $\gcd(a_0,a_1,\ldots ,a_n)=1$.

Now, using the above definition it's easy to show that $f$ irreducible in $R[X]$ implies that $f$ is *primitive* in $R[X]$ and moreover that ii) implies i), without any extra assumption on $R$, but in general $f$ irreducible in $R[X]$ doesn't imply $f$ irreducible in $K[X]$.

> This leads to the following question: what extra conditions we need to guarantee that $f$ irreducible in $R[X]$ implies that $f$ is irreducible in $K[X]$?
>
> Is there any research papers about the question above?

Comment: See the comprehensive survey by D.D. Anderson: *GCD domains, Gauss' lemma, and contents of polynomials*, 2000

Comment: $2X^2 + 2X + 3$ is irreducible over the Dedekind ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ but reducible over its fraction field. This may help you corner the desired  generalizations of GCD rings you are looking for.